# Calling Functions in Main Function

Tags: python

I've written a program and want to call the functions in the main. However, I've been receiving a SyntaxError. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code, I've tried a few things but the main function won't call the rest of the functions.

```
class Matrix(object):
    def open_file():
        '''Opens the file if it exists, otherwise prints out error message'''
        Done = False
        while not Done: 
            try:
                File = input("Enter a filename: ").lower() #Asks user for a file to input
                Open_File = open(File, "r") #Open the file if it exists and reads it 
                Info = Open_File.readlines()[1:]
                Open_File.close() #Close the file 
                Done = True #Exits the while loop 
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print("Sorry that file doesn't exist!") #prints out error message if file doesn't exist
            return Info #Info is the file_pointer(fp)

    def __init__(self):  # This completed method is given
        '''Create and initialize your class attributes.'''
        self._matrix = {} #Intialize the matrix
        self._rooms = 0 #Set the rooms equal to zero

    def read_file(self, Info): #Info is equvalient to the file pointer or fp
        '''Build an adjacency matrix that you read from a file fp.'''
        self._rooms = Info.readline()
        self._rooms = int(self._rooms)
        for line in Info:
            a, b = map(int, line.split())
            self._matrix.setdefault(a, set()).add(b)
            self._matrix.setdefault(b, set()).add(a)

        return self._rooms and self._matrix

    def __str__(self):
        '''Return the adjacency matrix as a string.'''
        s = str(self._matrix)
        return s  #__str__ always returns a string

    def main(self):
        matrix = Matrix()
        info = matrix.open_file()
        matrix.read_file(info)
        s = str(matrix)
        print(s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   m = Matrix()
   m.main()
```

Comment: Which line is the syntax error complaining about?

Comment: Are you sure you want the `main` function to be in the class definition? That means you have to call it as `m = Matrix()` and `m.main()`

Comment: Basically all the lines in def main(self):

Comment: You can't assign to a function call like `open_file() = Info`. What are you expecting that to do?

Comment: Variable assignments are like `Info = open_file()`.

Comment: And it should be `self.open_file()`

Comment: Yeah, the indentation is identical in my file. I didn't know that the main function had to be called outside of the class definition. Does my main function, although it is within the class, look correct?

Comment: There's no need to call `__init__(self)`, that's done automatically when you create the object.

Comment: Python != Java...

Comment: It gives me SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Comment: It seems like you need to reread your Python tutorial on writing OO code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
This includes the full error message.  Most of all, you need to work with a few lines added at a time; you haven't learned quite enough to write this much code at once.  Take it easier, and you'll learn faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you may want to write something like below. Also, your open_file() has to be rewritten.

```
class Matrix(object):
    def open_file(self):
        File = input("Enter a filename: ").lower() #Asks user for a file to input 
        fp = open(File, "r") 
        return fp

#### Your matrix class code goes here

def main():
    myMatrix = Matrix()
    fp = myMatrix.open_file()
    ret = myMatrix.read_file(fp)
    print(myMatrix)


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

Comment: Yeah, open_file() is giving me the Error TypeError: open_file() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given. I'm not sure how to fix this however

Comment: def open_file(self):      File = input("Enter a filename: ").lower() #Asks user for a file to input
                fp = open(File, "r")              return fp

Comment: added the open_file function in the above code section to be clear,

Comment: Thank you Arun, this helped very much

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- it's `self.read_file`, not just `read_file`. It's an instance method so you need to use `self`.
- Same for `__init__(self)`, you need to call `self.__init__`. Although typically you don't do this manually. You would "instantiate" the class via `Matrix()`.
- You can't assign to a function call, so `open_file() = Info` simply doesn't make sense. Perhaps you mean `info = open_file()`.

It looks like you're a little confused about how to lay out your class. Try leaving `main` *outside* of the class, like this (untested):

```
def main:
    matrix = Matrix()
    info = matrix.open_file()
    matrix.read_file(info)
    s = str(matrix)
    print(s)
```

You will also need to dedent `if __name__ == '__main__'` to the global scope.

Comment: I appear to have put main into the class. I'm not very familiar with classes and I'm sure it shows so I just assumed that the main went inside my class with the rest

Comment: See my edit for a suggestion on how to write `main`.

Comment: So I put def main(): Outside of my class and then call it outside of the class?

Answer (score 1):

the way this is posted

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

is going to be executed *when the class is defined* -- not when the program is run. As written, the class won't have been instantiated so there's no `Matrix` object on which you can call `main()`.

You'll need to move the call out one indent, so it is aligned with the class definition, and then create an object before calling its `main()`:

```
  if __name__ == "__main__": 
    instance = Matrix()
    instance.main()
```

You've also got the assignments backwards in `main()`. It should read more like this:

```
 info = open_file()
 self.read_file(Info)
 s = __str__(self)
 print(s)
```

the `open_file()` method also has some issues.  You want to create `Info` outside the scope of your loop so you know you've got it to return.   Your comment indicates the `Info` is supposed to be the file pointer -- but it's not, as you wrote it. `Open_File` is the file pointer, and `Info` is the content of the file (at least, everything but the first line). Unless you're expecting a huge amount of data, it's probably easier to pass the contents -- or to combine `open_file` and `read_file` into the same function.

You also want to use the usual python pattern for opening and closing the files the `with` context manager - that will close your file for you.

Heres a quick and dirty version of `Open_file` and `Read_file` in one package.

```
def read_file(self):

   #get the filename first
   filename = None
   while not filename: 
       user_fn = input("Enter a filename: ").lower()
       if os.path.exists(user_fn):
           filename = user_fn
       else:
           print ("Sorry that file doesn't exist!") 

   # 'with' will automatically close the file for you
   with open(filename, 'rt') as filepointer:
       # file objects are iterable:
       for line in filepointer:
           a, b = map(int, line.split())
           self._matrix.setdefault(a, set()).add(b)
           self._matrix.setdefault(b, set()).add(a)
```

I'm not clear what `self._matrix.setdefault(a, set()).add(b)` is supposed to be doing for you here, but in syntactic terms you can simply the structure to "get the filename, open with `with`, iterate over it"

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your program's entry. ' if **name** == '**main**':'shouldn't be included in a Class. It should be global. And another, you want to call a member function of Matrix, but where is the object of Matrix.                                         The code below is correct:

```
Class Matrix(object):
#################
        your codes
#################
 if __name__ == '__main__':
        m = Matrix()
        m.main()
```

Comment: My answer is just one of the correct way. And your open_file function is incorrect too. It must be designed like 'def open_file(self)'.

Comment: Ah, I put self into open_file(). However it's giving me UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Info' referenced before assignment

Comment: Yeah, Compiler never make mistakes! 'info' was declared in 'try' scope, but you return it out of the 'try' scope. There is no 'Info' when you try to return. Is that clear?

Comment: Thank you so much, changing the position of the return allowed it to work without problem

Comment: No no no, not good enough. You should declare 'Info' above 'while not Done', like this Info = '', and you should change the return out of the while sentence. We should ensure that no matter what happens, we can get empty string in 'Info' at least. Hope it could help.

Comment: Hi RGPython I noticed in your code you use File.open and I recommend you to use `with` keyword when dealing with file objects because file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way, you cann read here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects